# How to create a table with left and top "captions"?

Tags: tables, tabularx, booktabs

I would like to create a table like the following (forgive the sloppy photo):

[image]

In particular, I'm having difficulty positioning the words "Input" and "Output", in addition to the standard "Table 1" caption at the bottom.

Any tips appreciated. I am using tabularx or booktabs packages.

Comment: \multicolumn can handle the top label.  You can put the left label outside the tabular, possibly using \raisebox to adjust the position.  You could also use the multirow package, but I see no advantage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As just mentioned by John Kormylo I have used `\multicolumn{}{}{}` for top caption, and adjusted the position by using `\raisebox{}{}` , and also used `\multirow[]{}{}{}` for left caption, used table environment for bottom caption, used `\centering` and `\hspace*{}` to center and adjust the `tabular` environment. And the result is shown below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=.45in,right=.45in,top=.6in,bottom=.6in,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
\hspace*{-2cm}\begin{tabular}{C{1.2cm}cC{0.5cm}|c|c|c}
\multicolumn{5}{r}{\raisebox{2ex}{Output}} \\
 &&      & \bfseries X &  \bfseries Y &  \\ \cline{2-6}
  \multirow[]{2}{3cm}{Input} && \bfseries X  & \bfseries A & \bfseries B & \\  \cline{3-6}

  && \bfseries Y & \bfseries C & \bfseries D & \\ \cline{2-6}

  &&  & &  & \\ 

\end{tabular}
\caption{Blah Blah Blah}
\label{Table:1}
\end{table}    

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Do not specify column formats in the preamble of `\tabularx`. Instead, you will need to use something like `\multicolumn{1}{C|}{content}` which will help you draw vertical lines only in certain locations. You also need to define a new column type `\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }` which will equalize column widths.

Here is the full source code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]


    \caption{Caption}
    \label{table:1}

    % Center the table
    \centering

    % Stretch the table (vertically)
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}


    \begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{ >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}C C C C}



        & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Output}
        \\


        & & \multicolumn{1}{|C|}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{Y}
        \\
        \Xcline{2-4}{0.2mm}


        \multirow{2}{2cm}{\centering Input} & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{X} & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{B}
        \\
        \Xcline{2-4}{0.2mm}


        & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{Y} & \multicolumn{1}{C|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{C}{D}


    \end{tabularx}



\end{table}


\end{document}
```

As an aside, "input" is not a caption to the right, it is just one entry that needs to occupy two rows in the first (hidden) column.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but I don't think this is a good way to present a table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

\centering

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2\tabcolsep}% double the default

\begin{tabular}{@{}lc|c|c|}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Output} \\
  & & X & Y \\
  \cline{2-4}
  \multirow{2}{*}{Input} 
  & X & A & B \\
  \cline{2-4}
  & Y & C & D \\
  \cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}

\caption{Blah blah blah}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is it bad? It's not at all clear what “input” and “output” refer to.